# Converting Fiona Collection to Geopandas GeoDataFrame?

Tags: fiona, geopandas

I have a feature class in a file geodatabase that I attempted to open with Geopandas, but I got the "list index out of range" error.  To bypass this error, I'm reading the feature class directly with Fiona.  This worked without a problem, and now I have a Fiona collection.  What I can't figure out, is how to continue processing this file in Geopandas.  I have been unable to find anything in the respective documentations about how to process an existing object.

I also submitted a [bug issue](https://github.com/geopandas/geopandas/issues/435) at github/geopandas.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Found a solution by replicating the read_file() function in geopandas/file.py:

```
# Build the GeoDataFrame from Fiona Collection
gdf = gdp.GeoDataFrame.from_features([feature for feature in fiona_collection], crs=crs)
# Get the order of the fields in the Fiona Collection; add geometry to the end
columns = list(fiona_collection.meta["schema"]["properties"]) + ["geometry"]
# Re-order columns in the correct order
gdf = gdf[columns]
```